# crash of pyqt5 for getting html

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to use `pyqt5` to get html of webpages.

However, when I used it for a few times, it crashed.

Here is my code.

It is a simple `for` loop to get the `google` html.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import os

class Render(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.mHtml = ""
        self.app.exec_()

    def _load_finished(self):
        self.page().toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.mHtml = data
        self.app.quit()
        os.system("taskkill /f /im qtwebengineprocess.exe")

url = 'https://www.google.com'
for i in range(10):
    result = Render(url)
```

Comment: Why do you use that "nested" `self.page().toHtml`? And why do you create a new QApplication instance each time?

Comment: Sorry, can you show me directly?

Comment: Can I show you what? I asked you two questions, please answer them.